# HTML Form Construction

Tags: jquery, html, forms, form-submit, radiobuttonlist

Assume I have 4 icons for (Horizontal bar chart, Vertical bar chart, Line chart, Pie chart)in a form.

During form submit, I would like to know which icon has the user preferred on.

Currently I am using, 5 images src placed together in single line.

Please help me to retrieve the chart type from the following.

```
          <div class="component">
              <img src = "/images/1.png" class="cr_chart" alt="V - Bar Chart" id = "vertical_bar"/> 
              <img src = "/images/2.png" class="cr_chart" alt="H -Bar Chart" id = "horizontal_bar"/>
              <img src = "/images/3.png" class="cr_chart" alt="Line chart" id = "line_chart" />
              <img src = "/images/4.png" class="cr_chart" alt="Pie chart" id = "pie_chart"/>
          </div>
```

Should I have to use hidden radio button here?
If yes, please help me to retrieve the chosen chart type using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this:

HTML:

```
<div class="component">
<form>
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="Vertical" />
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="Horizontal" />
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="Line" />
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="Pie" />
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
alert($('input[name="radioButton"]:checked').val());
});
```

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4jcma58/)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But I dont want radio button to be visible. Instead I want the icon images to be visible.